# Nodejs how to obtain TLS object from https server

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

I am using a https server using nodejs.  For security reasons, I have to change certain ssl parameters.  More specifically, I have to set/disable "client renegotiation limit".

As per the standard documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_client_initiated_renegotiation_attack_mitigation), i have to set or change tls.CLIENT_RENEG_LIMIT to my value.

Since, I am using https module, I have access to https server.  My question is how to obtain tls object from https server, so that I can set values.

I understand that I can set a few options while creating a https server as below.

```
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('app-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('app-cert.pem'),
  secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLV2 | ...,
  ciphers: [...]
}
```

However, I am unsure what exactly to set if I were to add values for tls.CLIENT_RENEG_LIMIT, or tls.CLIENT_RENEG_WINDOW etc.  I am assuming there would be some way to obtain a tls handle through which I can set these.

Any help here...?

Answer (score 1):

You can not obtain `TLS` object from https server object but you can use the built-in module `tls` to set the required option. Before creating `https` server, you can set values as:

```
   const tls  =  require('tls')
    
    tls.CLIENT_RENEG_LIMIT = ' required value'
    
    const options = {
      key: fs.readFileSync('app-key.pem'),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('app-cert.pem'),
      secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLV2 | ...,
      ciphers: [...]
    }
    
const server = https.createServer(options,function(req,res){
     res.writeHead(200);
     res.end('hello world\n');
    })

server.listen(8080);
```

> TLSv1.3 does not support renegotiation.

`https` module is dependent on `tls`, So whatever valid value you set to `tls` will be applicable for `https`

> You can not pass `CLIENT_RENEG_LIMIT` as `https` options because
> `options <Object>` Accepts options from
> `tls.createServer()`,`tls.createSecureContext()` and
> `http.createServer()`.

[See tls.createServer options](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener)